# RatingBar not showing all stars

Tags: android, android-widget, android-styles

I have this Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/bar_detail_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:max="10"
        android:numStars="10"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:rating="7"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:stepSize="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With android:max=10, android:numStars=10, android:stepSize=1, I expect it to display 10 stars, and generally show 1 star per unit magnitude of the value I pass through setRating(). But this is not happening. I am attaching a screenshot from the Android Studio Layout Preview; this is pretty much exactly how it is shown on my Nexus 5 too.

It seems to be calculating it correctly; for a rating of 7, it is shading 7/10 stars (ie, 8 x 7/10 = 5.6 stars).

I simply can't figure out what the problem is, here.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio Layout Preview]

Comment: I think 
android:scaleX="0.7"
 android:scaleY="0.7". this two line can be problem.

Comment: No, without scaleX/scaleY the 8 stars Android shows me, overflow beyond the view boundary. At 0.7 the view fits the screen perfectly.

Comment: I think ScaleX cut off your some star for solving the problem you can use your own style or custom style 
Like  style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the stars in a RatingBar are not resized by Android; so in my case there was only space for 7 of them. In Landscape layout I could see 10 stars.

Resizing the stars took some reading up; but eventually came across this:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160323223259/http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/

In my case, what did the trick was to define a style:

```
<style name="MyRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar.Indicator">
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dp</item>
</style>
```

Applying this style reduced the star sizes and fit it in the screen.

Answer (score -1):

**only ratting is 0-5/5 only this is 7/10**

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/bar_detail_rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rating="3.5"
    />
```